# How to make (what is effectively) a pointer in Java

Tags: java, pointers, static

I know that there are no pointer types in Java, but I have an array of objects, and I need something to work like a pointer to the first element of the array not matter what it is or how many times the pointee changes. This is for a Pokemon game I am working on, and in the Player class, I have

```
public class Player {

    public String name;
    public Pokemon[] party;
    public static Pokemon currentPokemon;

    public Player(){
        this.party = new Pokemon[6];
        currentPokemon = party[0];
    }
}
```

I need currentPokemon to always "point" to party[0], which is why I thought to make it static, but when I later add pokemon to the array, party[0] cointains the Pokemon but currentPokemon is null. How do I get this pointer-like behavior?

Comment: There are no pointers in Java. You can almost always do what you want/need to do, but you will have to think of another way to do it. It's a shift in the way if thinking. Why do you need these things to happen?

Comment: There are other classes in my project with methods that can change the Pokemon stored in a Player's party array, so I just wanted a more readable way to get the current Pokemon without saying party[0] each time I wanted to use it.

Comment: You can't implement a magic pointer like this in any language I'm aware of, let alone Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` members belong to the **class**, and are shared by all instances. Every time you create a new instance, you override `currentPokemon`'s value (in the constructor). Remove the `static` modifier and you should be OK:

```
public class Player {

    public String name;
    public Pokemon[] party;
    public Pokemon currentPokemon; // Here
```

**EDIT:**
With the last comment by Christian Cook I think I now understand the problem statement. `currentPokemon` is initialized in the constructor with `party[0]`, which is of course `null`, because `party` was just created on the previous line. Unlike a pointer in c(++), `currentPokemon` won't update when `party` does - it isn't a pointer, it's just a reference to the value `party[0]` had when it was initialized.

The easiest way to get the behavior you're looking for is to not store `currentPokemon` as a member, but has a method to retrieve it instead:

```java
public Pokemon getCurrentPokemon() {
    return party[0];
}
```

Comment: I had initially tried it that way, but currentPokemon is still null even when party[0] contains a valid Pokemon.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You can point to arrays like this

```
Pokemon[] currentPokemon=party
```

Now, party and currentPokemon are pointing to the same array of objects. Manipulating currentPokemon results in manipulating party.

Hope this helps a little. :)

Comment: So why not just use `party`? This isn't what he asked for.